# React ProgressBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I need to setup a progress bar. So when I press on the button  progress bar shows, the button and the content inside of it dispears proggress bar starts to go 0 100 and as well shows some text above, and
when it reaches the 100% progress bar disppears and text above, but after that new text shows. Thanks in Advance

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress'
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

const Content =(props)=> {
const classes = useStyles();
const[hideContent, setHideContent]= React.useState(false) 
const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(10);


function handleClick12 ()
{setHideEset(true) } 


useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setProgress((prevProgress) => (prevProgress >= 100 ? 10 : prevProgress + 10));
  }, 800);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}, []);

    return (
             {!hideContent &&   
              <div className='esetNod__info'>         
              <h3>Hello</h3>             
              <Button onClick={handleClick12} className='fix__button'variant='outlined'></Button>
              <div >
              <LinearProgress value={progress} />
              </div>
              </div>
                 } 
              
           
       </div>
                      
    
    )
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: You still have quite a bit of work to do on this. However, are you using VS Code? You could really benefit from linting... look up eslint extension on VS Code. Prettier is another good one. When I pasted your code into my editor it lit up like a Christmas tree with errors.

Comment: @TonyDrummond I have both installed xd

Comment: @TonyDrummond. The reason it lit like a christmas tree, error was i have not typed any imports into this question

Comment: could you rephrase what you are trying to accomplish here? it's kinda cryptic

Comment: progress bar that loads to 0 100% and after reaches 100% it dissapears and shows some text

Comment: @Tequila I'm afraid that wasn't the case at all my friend. This was after I imported MUI components. You have a random </div> outside your expression. Your click said {setHideEset(true) }  instead of setHideContent. Nothing is indented or formatted in a readable manner in your return code. This code won't even compile in React.

Comment: @Tequila like I said - you need a linter and formatter (Prettier) in your development environment. You're currently going down a much more painful path in your development journey that could be made easier with those simple extensions for VS Code.

Comment: @TonyDrummond my mistake, but I have them installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write something for you:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

const Content = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setProgress((prevProgress) => {
                const next = prevProgress + 10;
                if (next === 100) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setHasLoaded(true);
                }
                return next;
            });
        }, 800);
    };

    if (!isLoading && !hasLoaded) {
        return (
            <div className="esetNod__info">
                <h3>Pre load content</h3>
                <button onClick={handleClick} className="fix__button">
                    Load Content
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    } else if (isLoading && !hasLoaded) {
        return (
            <diV>
                <h3>Loading content</h3>
                <LinearProgress value={progress} />
            </diV>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Post load content</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Content;
```